# send http post request and get post code directly

Tags: php

I have this php code which sends a http post:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/response.php';
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $result;
```

My response.php should send a http_status_code 200

```
echo http_response_code(200);
// Do something more
```

Result:

```
200
```

That works! But now my problem.
If my processes, which will executed in the response.php need some time to be finish - for example 15 seconds - the request.php gets the result "200" only after 15 seconds.

Can I get the response faster, like:

1. HTTP Post will send
2. Response will send the status code 200 directly and will do some stuff after this?

Comment: You probably want to run this on a background thread via `exec()`.

Comment: https://devdojo.com/dev5/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-background

Comment: @Mitya in your link I need a PHPBackgroundProcesser.php
Where can I find this?

Comment: I can't vouch for the content of the article, but it means you need a PHP file to elect to run in the background. You'll see when you run `exec()` that you stipulate a file to run.